# MySql Master Master out of sync

Tags: mysql, mysqldump, master-master-replication

I have 2 MySql nodes with Master-Master Replication set-up.
MySql1 has read and write access and is in current state.
MySql2 has only read access and stopped working due to space issue.
How can I fix this issue and resync it.

Comment: 'increase space'. 'start slave'. If stuck on step 1. [unix exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) might be a good place to ask. if step 2. include "SHOW SLAVE STATUS" from MySql2. If anything else, include logs, versions, and commands tried. Edit question as required.

Comment: I've cleared some space and the Slave Status has the below error 'Last_IO_Error: Got fatal error 1236 from master when reading data from binary log: 'Could not find first log file name in binary log index file''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the 'Could not find first log file name' error means Mysql1 has rotated away its binary logs.

You will need to reinitialize Mysql2 [as if it where a new replica](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-snapshot-method.html).

`RESET SLAVE ALL` on Mysql1 to ensure it forgets about its MySQL2 before beginning.

Comment: thank you for your reply. Should I take a mysqldump on mysql1 and copy the dump file to mysql2 and import the dump file to mysql2?

Comment: yes - don't forget `--master-data ` as a mysqldump option to record your replication position.

Comment: Can I UNLOCK TABLES in Mysql1 after taking the dump?  Also, is there a way I could change my Master-Master Replication to Master-Slave Replication

Comment: you're missing `--single-transaction` taking the dump (assuming most data is innodb). With Master-Slave you just don't create Mysql1 as a slave to Mysql2 after the restore process. Don't forget `RESET SLAVE ALL` on Mysql1

Comment: I've stopped the slave and ran FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK  and also recorded SHOW MASTER STATUS before taking the dump. Can I unlock the tables in MySql1after the dump. mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases  --quick  --lock-all-tables | gzip > backup.sql.gz

Comment: yes, you can unlock after dumping from mysql1.